# Firestore chat app - Is there a performance difference between these two data models?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

A chat document only contains the participant IDs and the messages as a subcollection.

[image]

My first simple idea was to query for the separate participant IDs. But would it result in a faster performance, if I instead use the document name to store the IDs (in a hacky way)? I could combine them as follows "(user1ID)+(user2ID)" and set that as the document name (see second entry in screenshot above).

```
Future<Chat> getChatFor(String user1ID, String user2ID) async {
    
    // Option 1
    _firestoreDB
        .collection(chatCollection)
        .where("user1ID", isEqualTo: user1ID)
        .where("user2ID", isEqualTo: user2ID)
        .get()
        .then(...)

    // Option 2
    var chatDocSnapshot = await _firestoreDB
        .collection(chatCollection)
        .doc('$user1ID+$user2ID')
        .get();
   
    // return...
}
```

Because there can only be one chat object for each user pair anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of queries depends on the size of your data returned and not on the query itself. So the speed would be the same for option 1 or option 2 as long as you have indexing set for those fields.

But I would recommend option 1 as it would allow you to do more complex queries like finding out which chat does one user have.

Comment: You mean I have to manually create indexes or will Firebase automatically index such simple queries?

Comment: For such simple queries, firebase automatically creates indexes for you. Only time when you need to manually create indexes is when you have compound queries in which case firebase will let you know when by throwing an error when you query a query without a composite index created.